# How do I POST JSON data with react js?

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, react-native

I have below code in react js.

```
import React from 'react';
import imagesdata from '..data/images.json';

function imagedata() {
  return (

        <div>
      {imagesdata.headerimgs.map((experience, i)=>{
       return (
        <div key={i}>
       <div>
       <h1>{experience.webimg}</h1>
       </div>
       );
                  }
       )
        }
            </div>
  );
}
export default imagedata
```

After running this code I get error which is

```
 Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  19 |   );
  20 | }
> 21 | export default imagedata
```

Comment: The title is incorrect. The question is not about posting data.

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error in your code. There is an extra div inside map function `<div key={i}> *<div>*`

```
import React from "react";
import imagesdata from "../data/images.json";

function imagedata() {
  return (
    <div>
      {imagesdata.headerimgs.map((experience, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          {" "}
          <h1>{experience.webimg}</h1>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
export default imagedata;
```

Comment: please comment the section which contains the syntax error for clarity.

Comment: ./src/data/images.json
Module parse failed: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 385 while parsing near '...tube.png",
        }
    ]
}'
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 385 while parsing near '...tube.png",
        }
    ]
}'
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: The `images.json` json file is not in proper format.  you can validate the json here https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is an error in one of the import:

```
import imagesdata from '..data/images.json';
```

is missing a `/`.
Rewrite it as:

```
import imagesdata from '../data/images.json';
```